# Redirect to login page after session timeout or restarted application

Tags: javascript, spring, reactjs, spring-boot, spring-security

I have a spring-boot application, with front of single page application using java script and react.

When the app is upload I have a login page.

In uploading i redirect the app to the login page by using spring security.

Now I am trying to redirect my app to the login page if my session timeout or if I restarted my spring-boot-application.

Do you have any insights to a simple way to implement this?

Comment: Have you tried `<security:session-management invalid-session-url="/login">` or `http.sessionManagement().invalidSessionUrl("/login")`?

Comment: in the end i used java script to solved this. i used window.location.replace and i redirect the page if the server is down or the session ended. (i have a controller the ping the server every 2 seconds)

Answer (score 0):

We use spring boot with a React SPA. You can implement an API which checks if the current user is logged in based on a session cookie. If the API returns you are not logged in then change the SPA to the login page. Use `setInterval/setTimeout` to call this API in the background at regular intervals.